# Send colon headers with Postman

Tags: api, curl, postman

I want to send some headers to an URL.

I want send These headers to the URL. But when I send these headers, I get an error!.

- :authority
- :method
- :path
- :scheme

I want to send with CURL. (Now I want to test with the Postman)

How can I send these headers?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, take a look if your endpoint accepts these headers. And if yes, then which values a request needs to pass in the header.

And please, give more unfolded explanation. What the error is there?

Comment: The endpoint accepts these headers.
These values I want to send: 
:authority
:method
:path
:scheme

I can't send these values. You can test with Instagram site. Instagram send these headers.